# Laravel didn't obtain full path

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xampp

I have a Laravel app running on XAMPP. I did point the VirtualHost directory at `C:/xampp/htdocs/donor/public`, which `public` in this case is Laravel's public folder.

However after I've tried changing the VirtualHost directory to `C:/xampp/htdocs`, and added the following alias, Laravel's seems **not** to see the full path of the app (which is `http://domain.tld/donor`), and recognise only the `http://domain.tld/`, making it point to invalid URL.

This make all the resources loaded from the wrong URL. Notice that there should be `/donor/` in the red circle provided. (Such as, `http://url.domain/donor/css/file.css` becomes `http://url.domain/donor/file.css`)

The alias added is:

```
Alias "/donor" "C:/xampp/htdocs/donor/public"
```

How can I config this in Laravel so it does its job perfectly?

[image]

Comment: Show us youre settings of youre server and which webserver do you use.

Comment: Thank you, more clarity now.